# Field language - Multi language

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I have a node in Dutch and I want to get the field in this language.
When I do:

```
$node->field_name[$node->language][0]['value'];
```

I get the error:

```
Undefined index: nl
```

So I try:

```
$node->field_name[$node->language]['nl']['value'];
```

But that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I already figured it out:

> $language = field_language('node', $node, 'field_yourfield');

This gave me the language of the field and it was 'und' and not 'nl' as I thought it would be. The language of the node can be different then of the field. Learnt a lot about i18 & Drupal :)

Comment: if you found a solution, please post it as an answer to your question and mark it as accepted (after the 24 hr waiting period) instead of putting it in the question

Answer (score 1):

I use a function from this blog post to retrieve the fields value, it's quite handy as it allows you to parse the different values of the field (also it handles `value` or `nid`).
[Drupal 7 tip : Get field values from entity objects like nodes, users, taxonomy...](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-tip-get-field-values-entity-objects-nodes-users-taxonomy)

Regarding the `und`, I'm not very sure why is this happening, I saw this issue: [Field display languages are cached before locale has changed field language](http://drupal.org/node/1238042), but I have to wrap my head against this.

Comment: und means there's no language set, in most cases the language is set on the node, not on the fields, so all fields have 'und' as language

Comment: And is it normal to have und on field while the node has a language ? I haven't seen the option to configure individual language for the fields. Do you have some links to clarify this for me ? Thanks.

Comment: yes, it's normal. Unless you define the language of the field it will always be und, check [Gabor's blog](http://atix.be/Zk3), a must read for i18n.

Comment: Ok so, with core only field are `und`, if I put a module like [Entity translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) then I can have some `fr` fields instead of `und`. Thanks for the tip.